# Time between constrained datatimes

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, jupyter, hour, maintenance-plan

I need to calculate the operating time between failures of a equipment, respecting its operating schedule.

Basically I have a corrective maintenance dataframe with the start and end time in the format of the attached image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSc0S.png)

I need a python code that calculates the time in hours between the end and start of each maintenance excluding times outside the operation calendar (that is, I need the time that it worked and did not fail).

The operation calendar is:

- Monday: from 07:15 am to 05:00 pm and after 10:20 pm to 11:59 pm
- Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday: from 12:00 am to 5:00 pm and from 10:20 pm to 11:59 pm
- Saturday: from 12:00 am to 7:15 am

Can someone help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)